# The English Debate

Tags: riddle

> I have
>
> 6 articles, an insect, a calculator,
>
> a basic verb, a stack exchange, four spaces,
>
> a core muscle, some males, and some black goo.
>
> I have more, but I risk giving myself away too easily.
>
> ***Who am I?***

---

*Complete answers indicate what is clued by each phrase in addition to the final answer.*

Comment: Brandon_J, the issue you raised in a recent flag has been referred to the CMs to look into, as the tools available to moderators are unavailing. Hopefully you should hear something in a few days.

Comment: @Rubio I appreciate it!

Comment: @Rubio I haven't heard anything as of yet. I would let it go at this point (it's only 8 rep, for goodness's sake) but if it's what it's suspected to be, it could be part of a larger problem :/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you are

> Antidisestablishmentarianism

6 articles,

> **An**tidisest**a**blishment**a**ri**an**ism -  and each "an" contains an additional "a".

an insect,

> Ant

a calculator,

> TI (Texas Instruments) as suggested by GentlePurpleRain in the comments.

a basic verb,

> is

a stack exchange,

> SE

four spaces,

> Tab (in code styling, tabs are often set to four spaces)

a core muscle,

> Ab

some males,

> men

and some black goo.

> tar

I have more, but I risk giving myself away too easily.

> It is 28 letters long.

Title

> Antidisestablishmentarianism is a political movement that developed in 19th-century Britain in opposition the Liberal Party's efforts to disestablish or remove the Church of England as the official state church, thus being the great English debate, credit to ArnaudMortier.

Comment: Very nice! This is the answer I was looking for; however, the title and the calculator clue were intended to be clued differently than you answered.

Comment: @Brandon_J Would the title refer to the very basic meaning of the solution and the implied debate?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier could you elaborate (maybe in rot13) what you mean by "very basic meaning"? I think you are on the right track, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Brandon_J rot13(Gur qrongr bire jurgure gur Puhepu fubhyq fgnl yrtnyyl obhaq gb gur pbhagel bs Ratynaq.)

Comment: I think the calculator is rot13(GV (sbe Grknf Vafgehzragf)).

Answer (score 1):

Extremely partial answer:

> Core muscle - Ab.
>  Articles - Likely a and an, not the.